# I need to send SMS through my android app with content chooser option

Tags: android

I already tried below mentioned code.but it showing a dialog box "No application can perform this application".

```
private void sendSMS(String number)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "In Send sms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String message="Welcome to My App";
    Intent sms_intent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    sms_intent.putExtra("sms_body",message);
    sms_intent.putExtra("address",number);
    sms_intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sms_intent,getResources().getText(R.string.sms)));
}
```

instead of ACTION_SENDTO,I tried ACTION_VIEW and ACTION_SEND. But I didnt get my desired result.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you....

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
intent.putExtra("sms_body",  "text here");
intent.putExtra("address",number);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have the same requirement.. What if I am calling this on OnItemClickListener method and if I want to display the list of available numbers to user to choose?

Answer (score -1):

```
private void sendSMS(String encodedsms) {
        String toSendSMS = encodedsms;
        String phoneNo ="YOUR PHONE NUMBER";

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, toSendSMS, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMSSent!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS faild, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```